# How do I aim a Korok Leaf?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I want to blow apples down from trees in order to collect them, but have only managed to mash the basic weapon attack button 'Y' to swing horizontally, without being able to change my aim along the vertical axis (pitch?).  I can even change my camera, and it still won't aim any higher.

So now I have to climb the tree and hope that I can hit the apples, see, and not fall off from the branch there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Answer

I took the crazy idea of trying to throw the leaf using the 'RB' throw button, and it actually did not throw the leaf like I wanted!  Instead, it blew in my currently facing direction with that familiar reticle.

#### Etc.

So that seems to be the answer, and in case you **actually** wanted to throw your leaf, well, I guess I don't know if you can do that in the game currently. :P

This wasn't a huge issue, but wanted to post in case anyone else was searching for the answer by chance.  I was a bit too protective of my items in the beginning of the game, coupled with the durability factor, and didn't want to lose my leaf!  Then I found it's a common and replenishable item from destroying trees, and I'm not even sure if it has limited durability to worry about.

Comment: Keep your leaf safe. It's really a secret rare for use in the boss fight ;)

Comment: I only have so much inventory space (at the beginning)!  I can always go back to get it, at least in the Great Plateau area, or any area that has trees, right?  I've already discarded it in order to hold a diverse set of powerful weapons.

Comment: (jk lol ha ha leaf)

Comment: @Pysis Korok leafs can randomly drop from chopped down trees, so don't worry about losing it.

Comment: Ok.  I had mentioned that in the answer, but just wanted to be sure.  Thanks!

Comment: This also applies to the magic rods dropped by wizzrobe enemies. R lets you aim instead of throw.

Comment: Very good question and answer, this is a nice mechanic.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to throw to aim it.

Like any other weapon, all you need to do is face the direction you want the wind to go. You can actually charge the swing, using stamina, and get an awesome gust of wind.

Comment: Your post is neither nice, nor helpful. Please try to keep an adequate tone. It also does not seem you read OP's answer, which clearly explains that you *can* aim the korok leaf and how you do it.

Comment: Was just going to highlight that this seems to answer the point I mentioned, where the leaf does respond to the user's input for commonly using weapons, but this only achieved a horizontal aim, not vertical that I was curious about.